# Automatically exporting all functions (vs manually specifying __all__)

Tags: python

I have a `helpers.py` file which defines about 30 helper functions to be exported as follows:

```
from helpers import *
```

To be able to do this, I have added all 30 functions to the `__all__` variable. Can I automatically have all functions exported, rather than having to specify each one?

Comment: I suppose there are some non exported methods in your helpers.py, otherwise the `__all__` won't be usefull...

Comment: If you don't define `__all__`, all the public names (those not starting with an underscore `_` character) will be imported by the statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, by simply not specifying `__all__`.

Answer (score 9):

Actually I think Gandaro is right, you don't have to specify `__all__`, but if, for some unknown reason, you would have to do it then, you can filter keywords from dir():

```
__all__ = [ helper for helper in dir() if helper == MY_CONDITION ]
```

Comment: Good point. In fact you can determine the contents of `__all__` in an even more elaborate way in your module if desired -- i.e. you're not limited to a single statement.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't define `__all__` then all of the functions in your module will be imported by calling `from helpers import *`

If you've got some functions that you'd like to keep private, then you could prefix their names with an underscore.  From my testing, this stops the functions from being imported by `import *`

For example, in helper.py:

```
def _HiddenFunc():
    return "Something"

def AnActualFunc():
    return "Hello"
```

Then:

```
>>> from helper import *
>>> AnActualFunc()
'Hello'
>>> _HiddenFunc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_HiddenFunc' is not defined
```